# SwiftUI LazyVGrid - How to fix broken VoiceOver order?

Tags: ios, swiftui, accessibility, voiceover, lazyvgrid

SwiftUI's LazyVGrid seems to read its section titles and items in the wrong order when using VoiceOver. It will read all section titles first and then proceed to the items of the first section:

| Actual Behaviour | Expected Behaviour |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Actual Behaviour] | [image: Expected Behaviour] |

Am I doing something wrong? What can I do to change the order (apart from filing a bug with Apple)?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let columns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))]
    let collections = (1...3).map { "Collection \($0)" }
    let items = (1...10).map { "Item \($0)" }
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 16) {
            ForEach(collections) { collection in
                Section(header: Text(collection).font(.title)) {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        Text(item)
                            .id(collection+item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String {
        return self
    } 
}
```

Comment: try `.accessibilityElement(children: .combine)` for each Section, you can also provide sort priority for voice over so that voice over follows the sort order.

Comment: Even weirder  I would expect that combining children for each Section would result in the entire section being recognized as one VoiceOver-item. However it has no effect at all.

Manually setting sort priority should work, but I was hoping I could avoid that.

Comment: @NicolasBrunner I copied pasted your source code and directly got your expected behavior (Xcode 15.2, iPhone 13proMax, iOS 17.3.1).  It looks like your problem deals with a specific setting activated in your accessibility menu (which one?). 

Comment: Works correctly on iOS 15.7.7, iPhone 7. 

Additionally, you can try `.accessibilityElement(children: .contain)` on your section, which makes the section to be accessibility element, though preserve heading and items from merging into one accessibility element.